# React Native AsyncStorage: Cannot resolve promise returned by getItem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I have the following code that should return an item from AsyncStorage.

However the item is never read:

```
const key = 'shoppingListItems';

export default class ShoppingListService {
    static async getItems() 
    {
        let result = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);

        return result;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And I use it in a component (screen):

```
// ...

  componentDidMount()
  {
    alert(JSON.stringify(ShoppingListService.getItems()));
  }

// ...
```

It always shows me a message with:

> {"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}

How do i get the data inside AsyncStorage?

Comment: Are you in Android dev mode?

Comment: I am using the iOS simulator

Answer (score 4):

```
  async componentDidMount()
  {
    alert(JSON.stringify(await ShoppingListService.getItems()));
  }
```

I made the `componentDidMount` function `async`. I dont know if thats recommended, but this works.

Comment: Yes the problem was you not using async/await or using `AsyncStorage.getItem('itemKey').then(result => {})`