# AsyncStorage.setItem Promise not fulfilling or erroring?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise

I've looked through a few posts such as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701344/react-native-asyncstorage-cannot-resolve-promise-returned-by-getitem)

I want to use a console.log to see if I successfully set an item to AsyncStorage.

Here is my code:

```
export function saveDeckTitleAPI(key,title) {
  return AsyncStorage.setItem(uuid(), JSON.stringify(new DeckCreator(title)))
    .then(data => {
      debugger;
      console.log('INSIDE SET ITEM');
      AsyncStorage.getItem(data.key).then(item => {
        console.log(item);
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.err(err);
    });

}
```

When I run this code, the `.then` and the `.catch` aren't fulfilled. I tried logging the promise by itself, and I get a similar result as the post above.

Do I have to use async/await? Is that the problem here? Here are the docs to [setItem](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#setitem).

Comment: I have the same problem, and using async/await doesn't solve it. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback as the third argument. If there's an error, it will be the callback's first parameter. If there's no error, console log that all is well and good, otherwise log the error.

Comment: I have the same issue, doing this doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need `async` and `await`

You can get an inspiration from the code below, the way I do a facebook login with `setItem`

```
const doFacebookLogin = async dispatch => {
  const { type, token } = await 
  Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('xxxx', {
    permissions: ['public_profile']
  });

  if (type === 'cancel') {
    return dispatch({ type: FACEBOOK_LOGIN_FAIL });
  }

  await AsyncStorage.setItem('fb_token', token);
  dispatch({ type: FACEBOOK_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: token });
```

};